# overflow A into B

Tags: verb-pattern

Can a and b be combined into c?

> a. The crowd overflowed into the street.

> b. The crowd overflowed the auditorium.

> c. The crowd overflowed the auditorium into the street.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that a "wild card" search in Google NGrams for [overflowed the * into](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=overflowed+the+%2A+into&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=) produces no output, because the sequence is just too uncommon....

Comment: ...but if I include an explicit preposition [overflowed **from** the * into](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=overflowed+from+the+%2A+into&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Coverflowed%20from%20the%20%2A%20into%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Boverflowed%20from%20the%20towns%20into%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boverflowed%20from%20the%20church%20into%3B%2Cc0), I get plenty of hits. I suggest you do likewise, but this is basically just Off Topic writing advice.

Comment: If you google that sequence with double quotation marks on Google Books, you'll find some results.

Comment: Oh, wow! I didn't realise Google *Internet* searches can now handle that wildcard asterisk! I probably last checked that point at least 5 years ago, which just goes to show that things are constantly moving forward, and even things I discovered relatively recently might no longer be true! Anyway, I've definitely learned something useful from this question, even if you don't! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be clearer as "The crowd overflowed the auditorium, pouring into the street." Then it would be clear that the direct object in c., *auditorium*, is not itself being pushed into the street.

Comment: How about "He left New York for Boston"?

Comment: I think that's a common expression, so it's right by definition.